# Subtract Two columns off the condition of two other column values

Tags: sql

Having a lot of trouble thinking through this problem, but please view below example table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_1` 
(
    `num` float NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_1` (`num`, `first_name`, `last_name`) 
VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Wonk'),
       ('5', 'John', 'Woo'),
       ('3', 'James', 'Lee');
```

This is the output I want: "If first_name equals first_name and last_name does not equal last_name then subtract num with last_name = 'Woo' from num" So the result it would have 1 - 5 (using table data below) and the output would be -4

Comment: can you share the expected output in a table format.

Comment: What about first and last name is different? Your requirements looks strange for a db operation

Comment: What if there are two John Wonk? Or if there is a John Wang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Simple Left join on `first_name` equal and `last_name` not equal will align the `num` field with a value, when matched, or null. You cast null's to 0 and do your math for each records so that those that meet the criteria will adjust.

```
SELECT  
    D1.first_name,
    D1.last_name,
    num = D1.num - ISNULL(D2.num,0)
FROM
    table_1 D1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_1 D2 ON D2.first_name = D1.first_name AND D1.last_name <> D2.last_name
```

Comment: One uncertainty that you did not address in your question was if the num value should be negated for each match, meaning if there was another John Woo with the value of 10 would the first John Woo be -14 or would there be multiple instances for each match and for each negation?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select min(num) - max(num)
from t
group by first_name
having min(last_name) <> max(last_name);
```